# rbind and mapply - getting a matrix rather than a data frame

Tags: r

So, I'm trying to pass lists to a function that returns a data frame via `mapply`, then use `do.call` to `rbind` them all together into a single data frame.

Here's some dummy code:

```
var_1 <- list(1, 2)
var_2 <- list(3, 4)

output <- do.call(
    rbind,
    mapply(
      function(x, y) {return(data.frame(x, y, x+y))},
      var_1,
      var_2
    )
  )
```

Expected result: a data frame with 2 rows and 3 columns.

Actual result: a 6x1 matrix.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `do.call` you need to pass in a list of parameters. Currently your `mapply` call doesn't reuturn a list, it simplifies the result into a matrix. What you want is to prevent the simplification. You can either set the `SIMPLIFY=` parameter

```
output <- do.call(
    rbind,
    mapply(
      function(x, y) {return(data.frame(x, y, x+y))},
      var_1,
      var_2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE
    )
  )
```

or just use `Map()` which always returns a list

```
output <- do.call(
    rbind,
    Map(
      function(x, y) {return(data.frame(x, y, x+y))},
      var_1,
      var_2
    )
  )
```